# JQuery Mobile button click event not firing on iOS device

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, jquery-mobile

I am trying JQuery Mobile for the first time and have not been able to trigger a response to a button being pressed on my iphone 4S which runs iOS 7.1.  The click event is triggered in the browser on my computer but not on the device.  I can see that this is a common issue and have tried the various proposed solutions but they dont seem to work for me.  My code is very simple.  The markup is

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>title</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

<script src="javascript/idtest.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page">

<div id='login'>

<center>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" id='pincodebtn'>Identify</a>
</center>

</div>

</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

And the javascript, idtest.js, is

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#pincodebtn').css('cursor','pointer');

    $(document).on('click','#pincodebtn',function(){    
        alert('clicked');   
    })

});
```

As you can see, I have tried the trick of setting the cursor to pointer.  I have also tried catching the 'vclick', 'touchstart', 'touchend' and 'tap' events.  None of which trigger the alert on the iOS device.  Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
$('#pincodebtn').on('click',function(){    
        alert('clicked');   
});
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well.  It works on the computer but not on the mobile device

Comment: can you give more details? Your code and mine work for me. Are you using phonegap/cordova? or is a website?

Comment: I have put the full markup and the full javascript in the question now.  Thats it.  It is a website pure and simple.  Works on my computer but not on my phone.

Comment: It works for me, maybe you have javascript disabled on the phone?

Comment: I think you are onto something.  I tried on android and it worked fine.  I tried on another iphone and it worked fine.  I tried on my iphone on chrome and it worked fine.  It has something to do with my Safari on the iphone!  Its not javascript but it must be a setting of some kind.

Comment: Restarted Safari and it worked!  @jcesarmobile - thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: It's good to know that javascript can just stop working and you have to restart safari to make it work again.

Answer (score 0):

Try  the below code

```html
$('#pincodebtn').on('click touchstart',function(){    
        alert('clicked');   
});
```